# _AppDomainPtr Load_3 method example?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, clr, appdomain

I am trying to load a C# assembly with `_AppDomainPtr` `Load_3` method. Do you have some example since I get error:
`hr = 0x80131533 : A mismatch has occurred between the runtime type of the array and the sub type recorded in the metadata.`
Here is a snippet how do I load the assembly:

```
static void binarray(SAFEARRAY** output, const char* data, size_t size)
{
    SAFEARRAYBOUND  Bound;
    Bound.lLbound = 0;
    Bound.cElements = size;

    *output = SafeArrayCreate(VT_R8, 1, &Bound);

    double HUGEP *pdFreq;
    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(*output, (void HUGEP* FAR*)&pdFreq);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // copy sample values from data[] to this safearray
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            *pdFreq++ = data[i];
        }
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(*output);
    }
}
```

And the call:

```
hr = spDefaultAppDomain->Load_3(output, &spAssembly);
```

Anyone used that?

Comment: That's the AppDomain.Load(byte[]) overload.  It is not happy about you trying to pass double[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I've found the problem. I was creating a SafeArray of Real numbers. The correct fix for anyone who needs that is:

```
static void binarray(SAFEARRAY** output, const unsigned  char* data, size_t size)
{
    SAFEARRAYBOUND  Bound;
    Bound.lLbound = 0;
    Bound.cElements = size;
//  VT_I1
    *output = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, &Bound);
    //VT_R8
    unsigned char *pdFreq;
    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(*output, (void* FAR*)&pdFreq);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // copy sample values from data[] to this safearray
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            *pdFreq++ = data[i];
        }
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(*output);
    }
}
```